# What is the difference between Evernote and Remember the Milk?

Tags: evernote, remember-the-milk

I've interested in using some sort of online note-keeping application. I've seen these two mentioned frequently online, and have briefly taken a look at their websites. As far as I can tell, they are both note-keeping tools. Are there any substantial differences I should know about?

Comment: This is not the answer, but in case you are looking into an alternative note-keeping app, have a look at www.memonic.com.
Works well for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Remember the Milk is a task list application** first. The notes are not the focus here and the options are limited when it comes to taking notes.

**Evernote is a note taking application** and it specializes in that field.

If you need to take notes, use Evernote (or another note taking app but this one is good), if you need to manage tasks/todos and attach notes to those tasks, use Remember the Milk.

Comment: Aah, a task list. Evidently I didn't read deep enough into the purpose of RTM.

Comment: As an update, I am now using both tools. I appreciate their respective uses, and see how they are each good at what they do.

Answer (score 4):

The major differences are that Evernote is designed for note-taking, web clippings, and memos while Remember the Milk is focused on tasks with a due date. Evernote can hold many formats of information you find while RTM can send you reminders through email, SMS, or Twitter of set tasks.

Don't hesitate to try both of them out. I use both regularly.

Comment: So you use them as complementary products?

Comment: To an extent. The two apps are useful in their own way. If I find an interesting article to read, I might copy it to my Evernote account. If I have to read it before the weekend for some reason, I might set a task in RTM with a due date and have it text my phone when I should be reminded.

Comment: Good example. That helps me to understand their respective uses.